# 100% height is making div overflow

Tags: css

this question is probably pretty common, as i've been going over answers here for the past 3 hours. and still, no success.

I have a parent html which takes 100% height of the page. the body takes also 100% of the page.
In the body element i have 3 divs. i have the 3rd and last one, to take the rest of the page and leave no whitespace after it (which it does now).

tried `height: 100%;` on the last div and `overflow: hidden;` on the body element. this just stratches my page and removes the scroll bar (but the website still scrolls O_O ).

please help.

edit: it seems the question itself isn't clear.
I want the last div to take the rest of the page height to the end of it.

```
    #div1{
   max-height: 150px;
}
 #div2{
    max-height: 150px;
}
    #div3{
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
```

all nested inside a body element which is nested inside html element.

I also have hidden info which is required to show when i click.. so i do need the page to stratch, if any more info is added to the page (hiding overflow on the entire document is going to be a problem than)

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: It would help if you could post your code either here or on jsFilddle.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try this code:

```
<body>
   <div id="container" style="height: 100%"; overflow="hidden">
      <div>
          asas
      </div>
      <div>
          sdsd
      </div>
      <div>
           wewe
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Comment: not working. it prevents the page from stratching to show other content (for example if i add text) but it does not prevent the last div from stratching the page when there is no text. so basicly that's doing everything exactly the opposite of what i'm asking

Comment: ahaha, sorry. Let me try and redo this solution.